# Swing JTabbedPane how to set scroll width?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtabbedpane

I use the following code to create a JTabbedPane

```
new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.LEFT,JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
```

It results in a scroll that is smaller in width than the tab selection area

[image]

How can I make the scroll width wider so that it fits the tab selection area?

Comment: What do you mean? You want those two arrows to take the whole width?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Yes, and the arrow pointer to be wider as well.

Comment: Why dont you use a button instead. And adjust the scroll bar on the button click. This will hide the scroll bar and give a better look to your UI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extend `BasicTabbedPaneUI` and implement you own button in `createScrollButton()` providing new preferred size. It looks like `BasicTabbedPaneUI` has its own private implementation for these buttons - `ScrollableTabButton`. You can create something similar, like the following:

```
public class ExtendedTabbedPaneUI extends BasicTabbedPaneUI {

    @Override
    protected JButton createScrollButton(int direction) {
         if (direction != SOUTH && direction != NORTH && direction != EAST &&
                                   direction != WEST) {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Direction must be one of: " +
                                                "SOUTH, NORTH, EAST or WEST");
         }

         //return new ScrollableTabButton(direction);

         return new BasicArrowButton(direction,
            UIManager.getColor("TabbedPane.selected"),
            UIManager.getColor("TabbedPane.shadow"),
            UIManager.getColor("TabbedPane.darkShadow"),
            UIManager.getColor("TabbedPane.highlight")) {

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                int maxWidth = calculateMaxTabWidth(JTabbedPane.LEFT);
                return new Dimension(maxWidth, super.getPreferredSize().height);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And to setup new UI:

```
tabbedPane.setUI(new ExtendedTabbedPaneUI());
```

Comment: For customization, you could also extend **MetalTabbedPaneUI**, override **createScrollButton()** like Aqua proposed, then return a new **ScrollableTabButton()** instead of **BasicArrowButton** if you get glitches like I do. The class **ScrollableTabButton** is defined in [BasicTabbedPaneUI](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicTabbedPaneUI.java.html).